# How Can I Get A Crash report From a Jailbroken App Running In My Device?

Tags: ios, ios4, ios-simulator, jailbreak, crash-reports

My Application is for jailbroken devices. It compiles and works fine in general in the iOS simulator but it crashes instantly the moment I open it in my device. Again, it's a Jailbroken app so I can't get crash logs the same way registered developers can. Is there any way I can get a crashlog for my app even though I am not a registered iOS developer? This is driving me nuts because I have been working on this for 3 months now and I don't want to stop because of something like this.

Oh, if it matters, I am "Fake code signing" using the method described [here](http://hacker-pro.com/forum/index.php?topic=271.0%20here), but only this specific app is crashing. I tested by making a dummy app that simply shows a label and it's not crashing at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Install OpenSSH in Cydia, then ssh into your device and navigate to `/var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter`. You will find all of the crash logs there.

Another way to diagnose the problem would be to install the syslogd enabler from Cydia. This will enable the syslog in /var/log/syslog. You can monitor this just like you would monitor Console is Mac OS X. Be sure to uninstall the syslogd enabler when you're not using it as the syslog can get pretty big after a while. You can also install the syslogd toggle for SBSettings to easily enable and disable syslogd.

Answer (score 0):

@edc1591's answer is still correct, but just for the sake of completeness I would like to add another answer for those seeking additional information. There is an package in Cydia, [CrashReporter](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/crash-reporter/), which offers an easy way to access the crash logs on the device (they can be sent via email from an app). Further advantages of using it include:

1. The crash logs are already symbolicated
2. A syslog is also included (assuming the package was installed prior to the crash)

It is very useful for collecting crash reports for tweaks from users who may not want to install or use OpenSSH. There is a very good explanation of how to use the app here: http://tweakcrashed.com/

The project is [open-source](https://github.com/ashikase).

Answer (score 0):

As most of the answers are outdated for newer iOS versions and after some time I was able to get this way to work properly.

The following worked for me on a Linux machine with a JailBroken iPhone 7 iOS version `15.7.9`:

1. Get and install by following the README: https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libplist.git
2. Get and install by following the README: https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice-glue.git
3. Get and install by following the README: https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice.git
4. Run `sudo ldconfig` to configure your Linux system.
5. Run `idevicesyslog | grep <your app name>` to get your logs.